# How would I implement this service/dll in a Unity project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, jnbridge

I'm using a service called JNBridge which is used to create proxies for Java files to be used in C#. The service works fine and I can easily create a C# solution in Visual Studio 2017 and call Java files from created proxies. I would like to use this in a Unity project however but I'm not sure how I would accomplish this.

In order to get this to work in Visual Studio 2017 I first create the proxies I want to use and build it into a dll. After that I create a console application and add the .dll as a reference (+ another .dll needed by the service). The service also needs to use an Application Configuration File and a non .NET .dll. These two files have to get copied to the build folder in order to run the application.

When I try recreating this in Unity I add the two .NET .dll files to the Assets folder and it seems to work since scripts autocomplete code from the .dlls. However in the Unity console I get a `FileNotFoundException`. I also have no idea how I would go about including the non .NET dll and the config file.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetToJavaProxies, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'DotNetToJavaProxies, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes()
```

I'm not that familiar with Unity so I'm asking, can I accomplish this? Using the config file and the .dll, and fixing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNBridgePro does not support Unity, so it is unlikely that this would work, although I have to say that we have never tried it. Starting with the new version 10, JNBridgePro does support .NET Framework and also .NET Core 3.0 (on Windows and Linux). Perhaps one of those scenarios would work for you. If you have additional questions, please contact JNBridge support.

Comment: Are you releasing a ".NET Standard" library or are you only releasing assemblies for core and the full framework?

Comment: We are considering it, but don't have a timeline currently.

Comment: I managed to get it sort of working. The main problem was that JNBShare.dll uses AppDomain which Unity does not support. I extracted the JNBShare.dll source code with ILSpy and built a version that didn't use AppDomain. This works but the proxy dll complains since the version I built is not signed with your private key. However building the project in Unity with the original JNBShare.dll and then replacing it with the version I built (and also putting the jnbauth_x64.dll in the same folder as the exe) works.

Comment: This is interesting to know, but I have to point out that you really shouldn't do this, as it violates our license.

Comment: Yes of course, I am aware of this and did it merely as a proof of concept.

Comment: Excuse the late reply, I apparently didn't have notifications on.